# Incorrect Syntax in T-SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have T-SQL Statement in my Stored Procedure which gives me error.But the same query runs very well in Query Window.
It gives Error Saying

> Incorret Syntax Near '.'

```
Set @SQL='Select ''<a href="javascript:editTicketByIDAction('' + 
          CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + '')">'' + 
          CONVERT(VarChar(Max),t1.Ticket) + 
          ''</a>'' t1.Ticket,VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket], Comments 
From VendorTickets t1 
WHERE NotifyOn <= GetDate() And NotifyOn Is Not Null AND 
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM VendorTickets t2 
WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket AND t1.InitiatedOn < t2.InitiatedOn)'

Exec(@SQL)
```

Without T-SQL it works well

```
    SELECT t1.Ticket,t1.VendorTicket,t1.Comments 
FROM VendorTickets t1 WHERE 
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM VendorTickets t2 
WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket AND t1.InitiatedOn < t2.InitiatedOn)
AND  NotifyOn <= GetDate() And NotifyOn Is Not Null
```

Comment: Why user `EXEC` instead of `sp_executeSql`? Anyway, what does `@SQL` look like when it goes worng? Is there a `'.'` in the Ticket field?

Comment: Write your query *without* the `SET @SQL = ` first.  This will allow much simpler debugging.  Then, once it works, you can return it to the Dynamic SQL layout.  *(Although, I'm not at all sure why you are using Dynamic SQL for this at all?)*

Comment: Did you want to alias the column? In that case you should remove `t1.` after last apostrophe.

Comment: @Jodrell Why use dynamic SQL at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing a `+`

```
... + '</a>' +  t1.Ticket ...
             ^------------------------here
```

Comment: So the "same" query wouldn't run well in query window. I thought so...

Comment: xObj = {"Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric."}

Comment: @SagarDumbre: If it is not a valid number you can't convert it to number.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `+` in two places. Try this:

```
Set @SQL='Select + ''<a href="javascript:editTicketByIDAction('' + 
          CONVERT(VarChar(Max), Ticket) + '')">'' + 
          CONVERT(VarChar(Max),t1.Ticket) + 
          ''</a>'' + t1.Ticket,VendorTicket[Vendor Ticket], Comments 
From VendorTickets t1 
WHERE NotifyOn <= GetDate() And NotifyOn Is Not Null AND 
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM VendorTickets t2 
WHERE t1.Ticket = t2.Ticket AND t1.InitiatedOn < t2.InitiatedOn)'

Exec(@SQL)
```